# How good BaasBox is with IonicFramework?

Tags: ionic-framework, baasbox

I am trying to build a realtime data app,it tried with **firebase** and it works very smoothly,but its too costly to scale up.
I found [BaasBox](http://www.baasbox.com),please suggest me how its easy and good to use for the Realtime data app.
Is there documentations and supports available for ionic + BaasBox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Amoeba I assume that by now you have found the answer. Am responding so other people with similar question may benefit.

Baasbox has very good documentation and is very easy to set up on local machine. For the production site though I would suggest looking at their cloud service. It is a viable replacement for firebase and has most of the features that firebase offers.

re ionic + BaasBox - Baasbox is a server side and provides a Javascript SDK for client side http://www.baasbox.com/documentation/?javascript#javascript-sdk. This library should be enough to integrate into your ionic project.

Since most of your client side code is likely to be AngularJS + Javascript, I would recommend writing services that encapsulate the Baasbox calls and then swapping those services in place of your firebase services. Most likely you will need some code rewrite as the interfaces signatures may be different between firebase and baasbox. Also as of now some of the API are not available yet in the Javascript SDK, so you may have to implement the calls by referring to equivalent Curl commands and then writing the calls using the $http angularjs service.  The data migration will take some careful consideration. I haven't tried such a data migration though so I would say best to get in touch with baasbox support for details.